# Error in from clause using sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to use SQL to return all entries from a user's friends.
The logic is that the session id is set as user id, which corresponds to a user's ID in the user table.
This should then link to either linkID1 or linkID2 in the friendslink table

```
    $sql = 
"SELECT * 
FROM ubuser
INNER JOIN ubFriendsLink
ON ubuser.usr_ID=ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1 
OR ubuser.usr_ID=ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2
WHERE ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1= ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] ."
OR ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2= ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] ."
GROUP BY ubuser.usr_ID;";
```

Edit: I have changed the statement so it no longer contains *, however i am now getting the following error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine Description: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'usr_firstname' as part of an aggregate function.'

The ammended sql looks like this:

```
 $sql = 
 "SELECT ubuser.usr_ID, ubuser.usr_firstname, ubuser.usr_lastname,
ubuser.usr_DOB,ubuser.usr_email 
FROM ubuser
INNER JOIN ubFriendsLink
ON ubuser.usr_ID=ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1 
OR ubuser.usr_ID=ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2
WHERE ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1= ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] ."
OR ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2= ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] ."
GROUP BY ubuser.usr_ID;";
```

However, the above code generates an error in from clause. Any ideas please?

Comment: Please share the exact error with us :)

Comment: "generates an error" is meaningless to us. You have the exact error message right in front of you; there is absolutely no reason for you not to include it in your question.

Comment: Since you are using GROUP BY you can't have * in the SELECT

Comment: my apologies: the exact error is Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine Description: Syntax error in FROM clause.'

Comment: Pretty lousy error description from `Microsoft JET` ..

Comment: Run the query on sql server (with sessions values) and tell us the error description.

Comment: Please use bind variables in your query to mitigate SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select all columns while grouping data.

```
SELECT ubuser.usr_ID
```